# xamarin.tesseract not working for android

Tags: xamarin.forms

Xamarin.tesseract is not working in case of android. After taking the pic it takes too much time to give the result and also result is not coming properly. It is giving wrong data instead of correct text on the image. Can someone gives the working code for this or is there any other open source library for reading ocr in android and ios both in Xamarin forms.

Comment: I've dealing with same issues here. It's working, but very slowly and far from accurate. I guess it's not a xamarin problem, but improvement needs on the tesseract 's library

Comment: Why not try Microsoft Cognitive services? Vision API

Comment: @RohitVipinMathews, I thought it doesn't have offline support. It do have?

Comment: @RohitVipinMathews I also need to scan mrz and Microsoft cognitive services do not read mrz from passport image. Let me know if there is any other solution to read mrz in Xamarin.forms or both native platform(Xamarin,ios and Xamarin.android)